# How to keep edited plugins updated?

Tags: plugins, updates

I find myself editing a lot of plugins because they never satisfy my needs, but of course I have to keep them updated.

I was thinking about register activation hook into some function that loads the interested plugin file and regexes in the proximity of the content I need to edit and replace it and save the file. If the regex does not match nothing gets updated so it should be safe...

What do you suggest?

Comment: What about `git merge`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent Plugin updates from clobbering user edits?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27248/how-do-i-prevent-plugin-updates-from-clobbering-user-edits)

Comment: does not seem to be a duplicate because that post asks how to prevent custom files stored in plugins folders to be deleted upon plugins update, I want to keep edits on core plugins files upon update.

Comment: Core plugins????? What do you mean? Are you modifying core files?

Comment: files core to the plugins, not to wp

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use Version control systems like Git, SVN, Mercurial etc. It will cover all your needs and more.

Comment: Hello, updating on this suggestion, I tried using git and svn, on the plugin I manually edited but it ended being too cumbersome, git/svn/hg are meant for project developing, not for applying small ad hoc patches for each project/plugin update, it is clear that if I would end up modifying some plugins heavily I would just fork them and stop updating them from the main developers or use git merge or both. But in this case the patches are too small to justify the use of a vcs, and it is simpler to bookmark the few changes and apply them manually on the updated plugins.